# Microsoft SQL create a summary table based on other group of tables

Tags: sql-server

My question is a bit simple, there are many answers to it but I have a question more about the query itself for certain conditions.

I have a table like this :

```
Client |    Date     | Employee | Last Record | Trained 
JOE    | April 2020  | John Doe | May 2019    | TRUE
JOE    |February 2020| John Doe | May 2019    | TRUE
JOE    | May 2 019   | John Doe | May 2019    | FALSE
```

Now I watn to make a simple SQL summary table saying :

```
Client | Date         | Inactive | Trained 
JOE    | April 2020   | 1        | 1
JOE    |February 2020 | 1        | 1
JOE    | May 2019     | 0        | 0
```

So basically do a count of Employees grouped by client and date, with the condition that the difference of date and last record is greater than, lets say 1 month and also in another column count the number of employees with a TRUE condition.

So my question is basically that, hwo would I go about creating a summary table where I want to set conditions per column, such as a date difference or if its true in a column.

Before you say Use a view, I need to create this table for performance reason since I am querying the first table which has millions of rows for a report program. However it is simple and better to query instead a table that holds a summary or counts with conditions.

Comment: Are you really storing dates as strings like `'April 2020'`?

Comment: No , this is just an example ,date is stored on smalldatetime format, last record is datetime format.    I usually make e xamples with generic stuff.